# 除了你我谁都不相信 or 除了你我谁也不相信 which is correct 都 or 也?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

I read that when we have two different meanings in a sentence with 除了we should use 都 and not 也(还)。 So from the two sentences above correct is like this

除了你我谁都不相信  means I believe only you

除了你我谁也(还)相信 means I believe not only you but others too.

Is correct what I mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

除了你我谁**都不**相信 = 除了你我谁**也不**相信 - I don't believe anybody but you.

I believe not only you but others too. - 除了你我**還/也**相信其他的人.

除了你我**還能**相信誰? - Who else I can believe but you?

Answer (score 0):

谁都不 and 谁也不, both are correct and have the same meaning (no exception). This is a popular collocation in sentences, that is **a question pronoun + 都 or 也 + a negative word**.

For example,

除了你说的，我**谁都不**相信。 = 除了你说的，我**谁也不**相信。= I would not believe in anyone else except you.

除了在家呆着，我**哪儿都没有**去。= 除了在家呆着，我**哪儿也没有**去。= I just stayed at home and went nowhere.

我**什么东西都没有**买到。= 我**什么东西也没有**买到。= I got nothing.

You have to translate the collocation as a whole, but not word by word.